# Safari can't open the specified address. Safari can't open "://

Tags: safari-5

I am trying to resolve a problem with Safari not being able to open a specific webpage

The problem that occurs when i log in to the website, instead of opening the account page, it displays this error message:

> Safari can't open the specified address. Safari can't open "://"
>   because the first character of its address is not valid.

The web address on this page shows

> ://

and nothing else.

When the back button is clicked, the correct page is opened and I am logged in.

I have Googled this error message and I've found nothing.

I have tested in older versions of Safari and other browsers and it works fine.

Safari 5.1.10 on Mac OSX

Comment: Does the same issue persist in another browser? It seems like there is a website issue more than a problem with your browser.

Comment: No.  It only seems to appear with this version of Safari.  Older versions of Safari works fine and in also works in all other browsers

Comment: Well, this is then probably an issue with the specific build of Safari. Do you need to have that build, would a previous version suffice? Or use a different browser for that site?